# Speed up Stanford Tagger in Knime

Tags: knime

I am using the Standford Tagger in knime and the performance is quite slow,

[image]

The set-up is:
[image]

It is a german hgc tagger, and the memory policy is: Keep only small tables in memory.

How can i speed this up?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I am using knime 3.5.0

Comment: That is pretty old. Why not update? Versions 4+  use system resources in the form of memory, CPU cores, and disk space more liberally and sensibly than earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

As this node is streamable use streaming option/extension available in KNIME. Also String to Document and Tag Filter nodes are streamable. Here is an [blog post](https://www.knime.com/blog/streaming-data-in-knime) explaining streaming in KNIME in details. It is older but still valid.

Comment: you mean for parallel executing?

Comment: No. I mean streaming